# Regular expression not working properly in case of multiple trailing ]]]]

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have the requirement that in a textbox a user can jump to the next word enclosed in [] on a tab out
for example 
Hi [this] is [an] example. Testing [this]
So when my cursor is at Hi and I do a tab out , the characters enclosed in the [this] are highlighted 
and when I again do a tabl out th next characters enclosed in following [an] are highlighted.
This works fine

Now the requirement is whatever the text including the special chars between [] needs to be highlighted

**case 1:** when I have trailing `]]]`, it only highlights leading `[[[` and ignores `]]]]`
              e.g 
            [image: Screenshot where on a tab ignores training ]]]]]

**case 2:** In case of multiple trailing `]` e.e `[`this`]]]]` is `[`test`]`, ideally one a single tabl out from this , it should go to next text enclosed in `[]` but a user has to tab out 4 times one tab per training ] to go to next `[`text`]`
               [image]

strong text
The code is

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('textarea').highlightTextarea({
        color : '#0475D1',
        words : [ "/(\[.*?\])/g" ],
        textColor : '#000000'
    });
    $('textarea').live('keydown', function(e) {
        var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
        if (keyCode == 9) {
            var currentIndex = getCaret($(this).get(0))
            selectText($(this), currentIndex);
            return false;
        }
    });
});

function selectText(element, currentIndex) {
    var rSearchTerm = new RegExp(/(\[.*?\])/);
    var ind = element.val().substr(currentIndex).search(rSearchTerm)
    currentIndex = (ind == -1 ? 0 : currentIndex);
    ind = (ind == -1 ? element.val().search(rSearchTerm) : ind);
    currentIndex = (ind == -1 ? 0 : currentIndex);
    var lasInd = (element.val().substr(currentIndex).search(rSearchTerm) == -1 ? 0
            : element.val().substr(currentIndex).indexOf(']'));
    var input = element.get(0);
    if (input.setSelectionRange) {
        input.focus();
        input.setSelectionRange(ind + currentIndex, lasInd + 1 + currentIndex);
    } else if (input.createTextRange) {
        var range = input.createTextRange();
        range.collapse(true);
        range.moveEnd('character', lasInd + 1 + currentIndex);
        range.moveStart('character', ind + currentIndex);
        range.select();
    }
}

function getCaret(el) {
    if (el.selectionEnd) {
        return el.selectionEnd;
    } else if (document.selection) {
        el.focus();
        var r = document.selection.createRange();
        if (r == null) {
            return 0;
        }
        var re = el.createTextRange(), rc = re.duplicate();
        re.moveToBookmark(r.getBookmark());
        rc.setEndPoint('EndToStart', re);
        return rc.text.length;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Please let me know to handle two above cases

Comment: This should work: \\[[^\]*\\]+

Comment: You do realize that you have two copies of the same image above, right?

Comment: @Danial , Please elaborate 
did you mean "\[[^]*\]+ –" instead of "/(\[.*?\]+)/g"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly the regex should be:

```
var rSearchTerm = /(\[.*?\]+)/;
```

Using `+` to match one or more `\]` at the end of the pattern. Also you don't need `new RegExp()` around a regex literal.

The next problem is that you are setting the end position of the selection with code that includes:

```
element.val().substr(currentIndex).indexOf(']')
```

Using `.indexOf(']')` finds the *first* `]` after the `currentIndex`, not the last one in the current match. You can find the last one if you use [`.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) instead of `.search()`, because `.match()` returns an array that includes details of the string that matched - from which you can work out the length of the match - and gives the index of the match.

Also, repeatedly calling `element.val()` and `element.val().substr()` is both horrible to read and inefficient - create a variable with the value. And calling `.search()` several times and using all of those `?:` ternary expressions to keep deciding what index variables should be tweaked to new values is just hard to read and confusing. In the end I just guessed what you were trying to do and rewrote it like this:

```
function selectText(element, currentIndex) {
    var rSearchTerm =  /(\[.*?\]+)/;
    var val = element.val();
    var matchStartPos, matchEndPos;
    var m = val.substr(currentIndex).match(rSearchTerm);
    if (!m){                             // if it didn't match
        currentIndex = 0;                // wrap back to the beginning
        m = val.match(rSearchTerm);      // and try to match again
    }
    console.log(m);
    if (m) {
        matchStartPos = m.index;
        matchEndPos = matchStartPos + m[0].length;
    } else {
        currentIndex = 0;
        matchStartPos = 0;
        matchEndPos = 0;
    }
    var input = element.get(0);
    if (input.setSelectionRange) {
        input.focus();
        input.setSelectionRange(matchStartPos + currentIndex, matchEndPos + currentIndex);
    } else if (input.createTextRange) {
        var range = input.createTextRange();
        range.collapse(true);
        range.moveEnd('character', matchEndPos + currentIndex);
        range.moveStart('character', matchStartPos + currentIndex);
        range.select();
    }
}
```

Working demo: http://jsbin.com/ewajoy/2/edit

Comment: One this I wanted to add is the above code works on Chrome but the text does not get highlighted on IE

Answer (score 1):

you need to adjust your regular expression to match more than one square bracket at the end. at the moment `"/(\[.*?\])/g"` will only match one square bracket.

Try this one `"/(\[.*?\]*)/g"`

Comment: Maybe `\]+` (that is, `/(\[.*?\]+)/g` in full) depending on whether the OP wants to match only when there's at least one closing `]`.

Comment: @DevZer0
 $('textarea').highlightTextarea({
  color : '#0475D1',
  words : ["/(\[.*?\]*)/g"],
  textColor : '#000000'
 });
this Doesn't work

Comment: `+` definitely works in Javascript. JS regexes are reasonably full-featured (no look behinds, but definitely all of the obvious stuff).

Comment: i think the issue is its not matching all of them. This regex should have matched the first one.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with this regex

```
(\[[^\[\]]*)+([^\[\]]*\])+
```

[DEMO](http://regexpal.com/?flags=g&regex=%28%5C%5B%5B%5E%5C%5B%5C%5D%5D%2a%29%2b%28%5B%5E%5C%5B%5C%5D%5D%2a%5C%5D%29%2b&input=%5Bfdsfdf%5D%20%5B%5B%5B%5D%5D%5D%0Ahi%20hello%20%5B%5B%5B%5Bworld%5D%5D%5D%5D%5D)

Comment: I tried ur suggestion as words : ["(\[[^\[\]]*)+([^\[\]]*\])+"],
Bit it doesnt work , I get the same issue tarining ]]]] are ignored or not highlighted

Comment: Please let me know If I can use it like 
$('textarea').highlightTextarea({
  color : '#0475D1',
  words : ["(\[[^\[\]]*)+([^\[\]]*\])+"],
  textColor : '#000000'
 });

Comment: @ronan I guess you have to use delimiters..Your regex in words would be `/(\[[^\[\]]*)+([^\[\]]*\])+/`

Comment: I tried with words : /(\[[^\[\]]*)+([^\[\]]*\])+/,
and words : ["/(\[[^\[\]]*)+([^\[\]]*\])+/"],
and words : "/(\[[^\[\]]*)+([^\[\]]*\])+/"
unfortunately it doesnt ignore ]]]]]

Comment: @ronan why arent you escaping `[]` to `\[\]` as i did in my regex